# WebLogic 12c - Error: ADRS_DOMAIN_PASSWORD environment variable not set

Tags: weblogic, jdeveloper, weblogic12c, oracle-maf

I'm trying to implement push notification in Oracle MAF (2.3.1) application. I need to deploy Push Server application on WebLogic server.

When i try to run **Integrated WebLogic Server (WL-12c)** from **JDeveloper 12c IDE**, I'm keep getting `Error:  ADRS_DOMAIN_PASSWORD environment variable not set.` in console log. Seeems it is not creating domain at all.

I have also attached complete Build log on below for your reference,

```
Adding environment variable to WLST script USER_MEM_ARGS = -Xms32m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m
Log File:      C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.0.42.151011.0031\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain.log
Label:         JDEVADF_MAIN_GENERIC_151011.0031.S
Product Home:  C:\oracle\Oracle_JDev_Home\jdeveloper\jdev\
Domain:        C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.0.42.151011.0031\DefaultDomain

BuildDefaultDomain1.py      2016-11-24 13:01:43

cmd.exe /c ""C:\oracle\Oracle_JDev_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.0.42.151011.0031\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py""
Process started
wlst > 
wlst > Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...
wlst > 
wlst > Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell
wlst > 
wlst > Type help() for help on available commands
wlst > 
wlst > Failed to get environment, environ will be empty: (0, 'Failed to execute command ([\'sh\', \'-c\', \'env\']): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified')
wlst > Error:  ADRS_DOMAIN_PASSWORD environment variable not set.
wlst > 
wlst > 
wlst > Exiting WebLogic Scripting Tool.
wlst > 
wlst > Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384m; support was removed in 8.0
Elapsed time:  13120 ms
```

I followed some steps to resolve this issue ([This article is for WebLogic 11g](http://www.techartifact.com/blogs/2013/07/error-while-deploying-adf-application-into-weblogic-server-11g.html#sthash.VTXPBp7N.orIcJDtO.dpbs)), it didn't helped me though.

Please let me know, if you want any more details. Any help would be appreciated.!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Mr.Hitham told, it is an bug for windows 10 version if you have upgraded recently.

> **Cause**
>
> Weblogic jython libraries do not recognize the operating system.
>
> **Solution**
>
> Oracle generated the patch 22138883. This patch fixes the problem ...

You could follow the steps as below (Added all the steps since I have seen may of the post reference links are missing or removed from corresponding sites),

### **Steps to follow:**

1. Copy **jython-modules.jar** file from "**\WL_Home\wlserver\common\wlst\modules***" as a backup.
2. Unzip it (Use Winrar, 7-zip., etc)
3. Open **javashell.py** file in editor from unzipped folder  "**Eg:*\WL_Home\wlserver\common\wlst\modules\jython-modules\Lib***"
4. Search for the following text **"_osTypeMap"**.

   ```
   _osTypeMap = (
   ( "nt", ( 'nt', 'Windows NT', 'Windows NT 4.0', 'WindowsNT',
             'Windows 2000', 'Windows 2003', 'Windows XP', 'Windows CE',
             'Windows Vista', 'Windows Server 2008', 'Windows 7', 'Windows 8', 
             'Windows Server 2012')),
   ( "dos", ( 'dos', 'Windows 95', 'Windows 98', 'Windows ME' )),
   ( "mac", ( 'mac', 'MacOS', 'Darwin' )),
   ( "None", ( 'None', )),
   )
   ```
5. Add **'Windows 10'** next to the ***'Windows Server 2012'*** as mentioned below,

   ```
   _osTypeMap = (
   ( "nt", ( 'nt', 'Windows NT', 'Windows NT 4.0', 'WindowsNT',
             'Windows 2000', 'Windows 2003', 'Windows XP', 'Windows CE',
             'Windows Vista', 'Windows Server 2008', 'Windows 7', 'Windows 8', 
             'Windows Server 2012','Windows 10')),
   ( "dos", ( 'dos', 'Windows 95', 'Windows 98', 'Windows ME' )),
   ( "mac", ( 'mac', 'MacOS', 'Darwin' )),
   ( "None", ( 'None', )),
   )
   ```
6. Open the command prompt mostly in admin mode, then execute the command **jar –cvf jython-modules.jar *** as show in image below (Make sure your jdk path shouldn't have any space, I have faced issue so just copied complete jdk fodler into **C-Drive**),
   [image]
7. Copy the latest jar file which is generated in **"WL_HOME\wlserver\common\wlst\modules\jython-modules"** into **"WL_HOME\wlserver\common\wlst\modules"**.
8. Now start the **IntegratedWebLogicServer** from yout JDeveloper. It will create based on new domain credentials and you could able to access the server console after successful creation of domain.

For any more reference, please check below links.

- [Reference 1](http://archlogs.com/en/development/windows10-soa-12-c-quickstart-integrated-environment-does-not-start/)
- [Reference 2](http://unversioned.blogspot.in/2015/12/jdeveloper-12c-generic-installer-cannot-create-weblogic-domain.html)

Hope this helps some one.! Thanks.!

Comment: I am having this issue on Weblogic 10.3.6.
Tried this fix, but still getting the exact same error.

Comment: Found the problem. Although I have Windows 10, the jython jar is searching for Windows 8. I figured out eventually to print the OS in the javashell.py

Answer (score 2):

> **Cause**
>
> Weblogic jython libraries do not recognize the operating system.
>
> **Solution**
>
> Oracle generated the patch 22138883. This patch fixes the
>   problem ...

Source: http://archlogs.com/en/development/windows10-soa-12-c-quickstart-integrated-environment-does-not-start/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'm checking it.!

Comment: I have done all the process, but could't resolve the issue. I'm suspecting that, each python file having class file. So, when we change  javashell.py file we need to compile it to get updated class file. Please share if you have any comments on this.!

Comment: I found the issue, the steps which was mentioned in the document was correct. But, instead of 'Windows 10' they have mentioned as '10 Windows'. When i changed it works fine.! In addition, I have also found this useful link.. https://blogs.oracle.com/emeapartnerweblogic/entry/jdeveloper_12c_generic_installer_windows

Comment: Glad you have it sorted

Comment: how to use the patch? i have downloaded p22138883_1036_Generic.zip and p22138883_122100_Generic.zip

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the steps which was mentioned in the document was correct. But, instead of 'Windows 10' they have mentioned as '10 Windows'.