# Jdeveloper - ImportError: no module named re

Tags: oracle12c, weblogic12c, jdeveloper

I'm getting the following errors when I try to start the integrated Weblogic Server in jDeveloper:

```
Process started
wlst > 
wlst > Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...
wlst > 
wlst > Error execing the Python script "/C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/internal/features/oracle.fmwshare.pyjar.jar!/wlstScriptDir/lib/PdkHandler.py" caused an error "Traceback (innermost last):
wlst >   File "<string>", line 1, in ?
wlst >   File "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\internal\features\oracle.fmwshare.pyjar.jar\wlstScriptDir/lib/PdkHandler.py", line 15, in ?
wlst >   File "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\internal\features\oracle.fmwshare.pyjar.jar\wlstScriptDir/lib/ProducerHelperHandler.py", line 21, in ?
wlst > ImportError: no module named re
wlst > "
wlst > Error execing the Python script "/C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/internal/features/oracle.fmwshare.pyjar.jar!/wlstScriptDir/lib/PortletClientHandler.py" caused an error "Traceback (innermost last):
wlst >   File "<string>", line 1, in ?
wlst >   File "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\internal\features\oracle.fmwshare.pyjar.jar\wlstScriptDir/lib/PortletClientHandler.py", line 14, in ?
wlst > ImportError: no module named re
wlst > "
wlst > Error execing the Python script "/C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/internal/features/oracle.fmwshare.pyjar.jar!/wlstScriptDir/lib/ProducerHelperHandler.py" caused an error "Traceback (innermost last):
wlst >   File "<string>", line 1, in ?
wlst >   File "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\internal\features\oracle.fmwshare.pyjar.jar\wlstScriptDir/lib/ProducerHelperHandler.py", line 21, in ?
wlst > ImportError: no module named re
wlst > "
```

I'm running jDeveloper on Windows 10 and I had the problem where I kept getting the adrs domain password environment variable not set error.

I followed [WebLogic 12c - Error: ADRS_DOMAIN_PASSWORD environment variable not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40780972/weblogic-12c-error-adrs-domain-password-environment-variable-not-set) and am now getting this error instead.

What can i do to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I've found the problem. Apparently the issue lies with the repacking of the JAR after editing. It seems to have trouble packing some files which result in this error. In order to avert this, you need edit the existing JAR and not unpack en repack it. After that it works fine without issues.

I used 7zip to do this but i'm sure others work just as wel.